# How to scroll to a particular content offset directly(without showing other contents )

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am using

```
[scrollView_Mag setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320 * currentImageView, 0) animated:No];
```

so that I can scroll to a particular View(as required). In code "currentImageView" is the number of the view, I want to scroll.It is working perfectly. Only problem is, That for example i am 320*10 point and I want to setContent offset to 320*2, It scrolls from point 320*10 to 320*2, thus showing all other stuff. Which I dont want. I want It to scroll Immidately and without showing any other Content

Comment: What is `No`? If you don't want it animated you need `NO`.

Comment: @rmaddy
i tried yes, no  both. But didnt work the way, I want

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrollView_Mag setHidden:YES];
[scrollView_Mag setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320 * currentImageView, 0) animated:NO];
[scrollView_Mag setHidden:NO];
```

When you move the content offset:

```
 //Define this BOOL in header
 isManuallyScrolling = YES; 
 [scrollView_Mag setHidden:YES];
 [scrollView_Mag setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320 * currentImageView, 0) animated:NO];


//Use the scrollView delegate method to see when it stopped scrolling
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    //If we manually scrolled, unhide the scrollView
    if (isManuallyScrolling) {
        [scrollView_Mag setHidden:NO];
        isManuallyScrolling = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: it too, didn't work. I tried it. It should have worked, Like I need. But It didn't. :(

Comment: thats a very good trick. I tried, it after reading your answer but the problem is It makes the scrolView permannetly hidden. i.e "- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView" is never called

Comment: @PiyushMishra 
Sir can you help me with this problem?
I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Any other hint, suggestion . will be greatful

Comment: @Jeev try the above implementation but set animated to `YES`. The delegate method may not fire since it isn't technically every accelerating or decelerating.